# How to use the same ViewController and not a new one on every click in swreveal view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have made the side bar using SWRevealViewController. When I click on items of side bar, it performs segue to set front view controller. Every time it creates a new instance of frontViewController, but I want to control it.

Suppose I have one of item name "Name" which on selection sets NameViewController as frontViewController. I click on name, NameViewController is set as frontViewController. Then I open again the side bar and click name, then it again creates a new instance of NameViewController and sets it as FrontViewController.

I just wanted to use the previous instance instead of making a new one on every click, if it is same item click again and again.

Does anyone know how to perform it?

My codes are below

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
       StampListTableViewController *viewController = [[StampListTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"StampListTableViewController" bundle:nil];
       viewController.categoryId=obj.categoryId;
       viewController.navigationTitle=obj.categoryName;
       UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
       [revealController pushFrontViewController:nc animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: set the pushed VC as a property of your current VC

Comment: thanks carl you made my day